# Oauth1 Error Constants Swift iOs

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class Base: NSObject {

let dataShared = UserDefaults.standard

func saveUser(user: User) {

    self.dataShared.setObject(user.token, forKey: Constants.OAUTH_TOKEN)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.secret, forKey: Constants.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.id, forKey: Constants.USER_ID)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.identifier, forKey: Constants.USER_IDENTIFIER)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.fullName, forKey: Constants.USER_NAME)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.crop, forKey: Constants.USER_CROP)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.state, forKey: Constants.USER_STATE)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.birthDate, forKey: Constants.USER_BIRTH_DATE)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.location, forKey: Constants.USER_LOCATION)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.channelGroup, forKey: Constants.USER_CHANNEL_GROUP)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.subdistrict, forKey: Constants.USER_SUBDISTRICT)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.hasStore, forKey: Constants.USER_HAS_STORE)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.storeId, forKey: Constants.USER_STORE_ID)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.type, forKey: Constants.USER_TYPE)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.privacy, forKey: Constants.USER_PRIVACY)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.communityId, forKey: Constants.USER_COMMUNITYID)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.customerId, forKey: Constants.USER_CUSTOMERID)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.points, forKey: Constants.USER_POINTS)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.avatar, forKey: Constants.USER_AVATAR)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.forums, forKey: Constants.USER_FORUMS)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.questions, forKey: Constants.USER_QUESTIONS)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.articles, forKey: Constants.USER_ARTICLES)
    self.dataShared.setObject(user.responses, forKey: Constants.USER_RESPONSES)
}

}
```

whats the problem withs Constants? i got Contstant Unsolve Indetifier

i used OauthSwift library from https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

how must i do to change this code ?

Comment: Is 'Constants' class a part of OAuthSwift library or one defined by you?

Comment: i dont know, i just found this code from example project

Comment: i dont know, i just found this code from example project

Comment: Hey did u get the soln?

Answer (score 0):

Constants in this example is just a swift file with variables assigned in it. They haven't implemented it as a class. So just access them directly using variable name instead of Constants.variablename.